# iOS project won't compile, just stalls with no error while copying swiftdocs

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, compilation

Suddenly one of my projects will no longer compile in Xcode. It just stalls at "Copying swiftdocs" and never gets past that.

[image: Stalls here]

Xcode is fully responsive, and the last line here indicates that it successfully xopied x86_64.swiftdoc.

All my old projects compile just fine.

Tried cleaning out the derived data, and all Xcode caches. And I also did a clean and a clean build folder on the project. Even deleted Xcode, downloaded 7.0.1 from the App Store again, but still the same issue.

What in the world is wrong here?

Comment: "Compile data model" is the build phase you're stuck in.  I have exactly the same problem. No solution yet.

Comment: I don't have a solution per say, but I've found that working backwards and opening up my datamodel after removing it from XCode and slowly incorporating the old data into a new data model file. I reached a point where XCode stopped being able to build and I stopped including data objects there. It seems arbitrary, but I've been able to work around the issue for the time being.

Comment: @CoreyZambonie Can you post an answer to this problem? (the solution that worked for you)

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue while 'Archive'ing at the moment XCode 7.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is a solution or explanation, but this happened on one Xcode project/workspace I was working on and then spread to others. I rebooted OSX and the problem seemed to rectify it's self.

Fingers crossed it doesnt happen again!

Answer (score 0):

At some point this just magically solved itself. I have yet to figure out what exactly happened.

Answer (score 0):

I had to pull out my CoreData model from XCode and reincorporate it back into my project. It seems arbitrary, but I've been able to work around the issue for the time being. Apparently others have just had this issue go away, but for me reincorporating the data model helped, as XCode was getting stuck compiling the data model.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved by rebooting the computer.

I guess that happens when you try to build project that is part of a workspace. It generate some kind of corrupt state.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the ONLY solution is **RESTART your mac**.

Before this I remember I tried all other troubleshooting options including the following but FAILED to resolve problem -

- Deleting derived data
- Clean project
- Quit and open Xcode again
- Archive multiple times
- Checked internet to make sure it was working.

Eventually I rebooted Mac and then directly launched Xcode again and opened my project and hit 'Archive' menu. There you go.. proceed with app submission process without any issues thereafter.